# Charging USB-C phone from USB Battery Charing Specification supply and connect wired headphones

Tags: usb-c, headset, audio-adapters

Trains and buses are often fitted with USB A power outlets, which presumably comply with the USB Battery Charing Specification, and often do not also have domestic voltage power outlets. I also have a collection of USB power supplies I rather not replace.

I would like to charge a USB-C smartphone which does not have a headphone socket whilst also connecting wired earphones with microphone.

Allowing an Ethernet connection as well would be a bonus. Slight preference for an adapter for 3.5mm headphone socket.

I have found numerous products that would be suitable except for the fact that they are not specified to be compatible with USB Battery Charging Specification, but instead just boast 60W of USB PD pass-though, and some state they stop working whenever the external supply is interrupted (as frequently happens on electric trains - especially on third rail).

I have found the [Star-tech CDP235APDM](https://www.startech.com/en-gb/cards-adapters/cdp235apdm) but even that has a contradictory specification.

Comment: Actually, the star-tech seems ideal.  What part of the spec is contradictory?  The other way to do it is to have a wireless charger, if you phone supports it.